# Workflows works slowly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, workflow

I have a problem with workflow. I use "State Machine Workflow" in project. Over time more and more workflow created, and application works slowly. After restart project application works normal, but after some time application works slowly again

Maximum working thread counts

```
int maxThreadinCore;
if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreadWorkflow"], out maxThreadinCore))
    maxThreadinCore = 5;
LogAdapter.Instance().LogInfo("Config max Thread" + maxThread);
var maxThreadCount = maxThreadinCore;
if (Environment.ProcessorCount != 1)
{
    maxThreadCount = (int)((maxThreadinCore* Environment.ProcessorCount) * .8);
}

var scheduler = new DefaultWorkflowSchedulerService(maxThreadCount);
```

When created a lot of workflow

```
while (loadedWorkfolows.Count > MaxThreads || totalMem > 1073741824)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    loadedWorkfolows = _runtime.GetLoadedWorkflows();
    GC.Collect();
    totalMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
}
```

This code is to be completed only in the case when there are no free workflows and we are waiting for new workflows.
If we will delete this code the workflows will be created while the system will be off free workflows and we will get the message AvailableThreads = 0

```
      while (avlThreads < 10)
      {
          LogHelper.Instance().Log(LogLevel.Debug,
          string.Format("AvailableThreads = {0}", avlThreads));
          ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out avlThreads, out avlPort);
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
```

When I set MaxThreads to 100, application use 100 loaded workflow and it works quickly enough. But after some time workflow begin to work slowly and I need to restart the service

Please advice me if somebody had a similar problem

Comment: Why do you need the 2nd code ("When created a lot of workflow")? I think that when your service is slow, this part in your code is simply executing endlessly. Calling `GC.Collect()` repeatedly will slow you down, and you shouldn't call it except in very rare scenarios. Also, blocking the thread (`Thread.Sleep(1000)`) for a second seems pointless. Put a trace/log around that code section and see if it is constantly executing when your service is slow.

Comment: Workflow Foundation is not suitable for 'real-time' applications. The state transitions happen on a separate thread.

Comment: @M.A. Hanin thanks for answer. This code is to be completed only in the case when there are no free workflows and we are waiting for new workflows. If we will delete this code the workflows will be created while the system will be off free workflows and we will get the message AvailableThreads = 0